# How to open a new view and killed the actual one?

Tags: ios, ipad, properties, viewcontroller

I have two views, actualView and nextView. Actually in the actualView, I would like to open the nextView and passing some properties (for example nextView.date = actualView.date) and killing the actualView.

I would like to know if it is possible ?

I used that code :

```
NSLog(@"Views : %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
FormViewController *formView = (FormViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"formView"];
formView.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:formView
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];

 [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I use **self.navigationController.viewControllers** in this "actualView", it knows where it is : , 
but when I use **self.navigationController.viewControllers** in the actualView, it is (null)... 
So may be a problem with the delegate ?

Comment: The problem with the segue, is that it opens views without killing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the two views with a present modally segue which will kill the actual view and go to the next view.
It is explained quite nicely here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

As for passing values from one view to another check out this function:

**override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){**

```
    if (segue.identifier == "segue identifier connecting the 2 views") {

        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  UINavigationController
        let detailview = viewController.topViewController as! nextViewViewController

        detailview.element defined in nextview = value to send
```

**}**

There are a lot of examples you can find online with performing segue with identifier. It is a very common question.

Answer (score 0):

Read something about `removeFromSuperview()` in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modal Segue.
This way actualView will be deallocated when you move to nextView.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an easier way than this :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *sourceViewController = self;
UIViewController *destinationController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"View3"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = sourceViewController.navigationController;

// Pop to root view controller (not animated) before pushing
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
```